# react-query, Invalid hook call

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I am trying to make a function to easily execute queries. Perhaps I initially did everything wrong, I will be glad if you correct me.
I created file Request.js:

```
import React from "react";
import { useQuery } from 'react-query'

export const Request = (method = "GET", body = {}, url = 'http://localhost:3000/notes') => {
  const parameters = {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    method: method,
  };
  if (method == "POST" || method == "PUT") {
    parameters.body = JSON.stringify(body);
  }

  const { status, data, isFetching, error } = useQuery("repoData", async (url, parameters) => {
    return await fetch(
      url, parameters
    )
  });

  if (status === 'loading') {
    return <div>loading...</div> // loading state
  }

  if (status === 'error') {
    return <div>{error.message}</div> // error state
  }

  return data;
};
```

And in index.js i called this function

```
import { Request } from './Request/Request';
console.log(Request());
```

But i have error
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.

Comment: You cannot call hooks outside of components. So move your ``Request()`` call inside one and it should work

Comment: Hooks *can* be called from other hooks as well, so if the purpose of `Request` is to be a custom hook then you should probably rename it to `useRequest`. OFC you'd still need to call this from within a functional component, but it'll at least get you past the likely next error you'd face.